# Как мне получить данные пользователя в вебе при авторизации в windows?

Tags: reactjs, active-directory, kerberos

есть потребность в том, чтобы получать хотя бы имя системного пользователя и выводить на веб в закрытой корпоративной среде. Получилось нарыть что то про **Active Directory** и **Kerberos**, но не смог понять как получить данные и вывести в веб.